# Why can't .click be substituted with an onClick event?

Tags: jquery

How come this code will work perfectly fine:

```
<script>
$('.changeStuff').click(
function() {
  $('#number2').val(12.00);
});
</script>

<body>
<h2 class="changeStuff">Lets change some stuff</h2>

<input name="number2" id="number2" value="11.00"> 
</body>
```

While this code, written to be used in an onClick event, wont work at all?

```
<script>
function change_stuff(b) {
  $('#number2').val(b);
}
</script>

<body>
<h2 onclick="change_stuff('12.00')">Lets change some stuff</h2>

<input name="number2" id="number2" value="11.00"> 
</body>
```

Comment: How did you test it to see the second code fail? Which conditions (browser, OS, complete code)?

Comment: It works for me. http://jsbin.com/ajuko3 That said, I'm not sure why you'd prefer the second method over the first.

Answer (score 1):

I think the `h2` element doesn't have an `onclick` event in all browsers.
That's why the second way might work but now in all browsers.
When you run a jQuery selector on the `h2` element the jQuery library "wrapped" the element
giving it all of the jQuery events and function.

And then because the jQuery object has a `click` event and jQuery works an all browsers
that way worked for you.

So thanks again to jQuery! for making our lives easier.